# adjusting angularjs material design data table column width

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using the old AngularJS Material Design Data Table and would like to know how to adjust the column width.

https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table

For instance if I wanted to change the 'fat' column in the demo to a fixed width of 40px how would I go about this?

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjvLVJ

There is a fixed padding which seems to be the main problem.

```
table.md-table.md-row-select td.md-cell:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(n+2), table.md-table.md-row-select th.md-column:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(n+2) {
￼    padding: 0 56px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following css class.

```
.width-override{
  width:40px !important;
  padding:0px !important;
}
```

You will need to add it to the `th` and `td` tags of the respective column like so.

```
<th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="fat.value" class="width-override"><span>Fat (g)</span></th>

<td md-cell class="width-override">{{dessert.fat.value | number: 2}}</td>
```

Please checkout the below example!

***Note: The contents are of width `56px` so the column is of that width, you might want to use the same, since we do not want to clip the contents inside the column.***

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ngMaterial', 'md.data.table'])

.config(['$mdThemingProvider', function ($mdThemingProvider) {
    'use strict';
    
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
      .primaryPalette('blue');
}])

.controller('nutritionController', ['$mdEditDialog', '$q', '$scope', '$timeout', function ($mdEditDialog, $q, $scope, $timeout) {
  'use strict';
  
  $scope.selected = [];
  $scope.limitOptions = [5, 10, 15];
  
  $scope.options = {
    rowSelection: true,
    multiSelect: true,
    autoSelect: true,
    decapitate: false,
    largeEditDialog: false,
    boundaryLinks: false,
    limitSelect: true,
    pageSelect: true
  };
  
  $scope.query = {
    order: 'name',
    limit: 5,
    page: 1
  };
  
  $scope.desserts = {
    "count": 9,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Frozen yogurt",
        "type": "Ice cream",
        "calories": { "value": 159.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 6.0 },
        "carbs": { "value": 24.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 4.0 },
        "sodium": { "value": 87.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 14.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 1.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "Ice cream sandwich",
        "type": "Ice cream",
        "calories": { "value": 237.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 9.0 },
        "carbs": { "value": 37.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 4.3 },
        "sodium": { "value": 129.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 8.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 1.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "Eclair",
        "type": "Pastry",
        "calories": { "value":  262.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 16.0 },
        "carbs": { "value": 24.0 },
        "protein": { "value":  6.0 },
        "sodium": { "value": 337.0 },
        "calcium": { "value":  6.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 7.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "Cupcake",
        "type": "Pastry",
        "calories": { "value":  305.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 3.7 },
        "carbs": { "value": 67.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 4.3 },
        "sodium": { "value": 413.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 3.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 8.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "Jelly bean",
        "type": "Candy",
        "calories": { "value":  375.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 0.0 },
        "carbs": { "value": 94.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 0.0 },
        "sodium": { "value": 50.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 0.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 0.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "Lollipop",
        "type": "Candy",
        "calories": { "value": 392.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 0.2 },
        "carbs": { "value": 98.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 0.0 },
        "sodium": { "value": 38.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 0.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 2.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "Honeycomb",
        "type": "Other",
        "calories": { "value": 408.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 3.2 },
        "carbs": { "value": 87.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 6.5 },
        "sodium": { "value": 562.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 0.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 45.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "Donut",
        "type": "Pastry",
        "calories": { "value": 452.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 25.0 },
        "carbs": { "value": 51.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 4.9 },
        "sodium": { "value": 326.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 2.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 22.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "KitKat",
        "type": "Candy",
        "calories": { "value": 518.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 26.0 },
        "carbs": { "value": 65.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 7.0 },
        "sodium": { "value": 54.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 12.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 6.0 }
      }
    ]
  };
  
  $scope.editComment = function (event, dessert) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // in case autoselect is enabled
    
    var editDialog = {
      modelValue: dessert.comment,
      placeholder: 'Add a comment',
      save: function (input) {
        if(input.$modelValue === 'Donald Trump') {
          input.$invalid = true;
          return $q.reject();
        }
        if(input.$modelValue === 'Bernie Sanders') {
          return dessert.comment = 'FEEL THE BERN!'
        }
        dessert.comment = input.$modelValue;
      },
      targetEvent: event,
      title: 'Add a comment',
      validators: {
        'md-maxlength': 30
      }
    };
    
    var promise;
    
    if($scope.options.largeEditDialog) {
      promise = $mdEditDialog.large(editDialog);
    } else {
      promise = $mdEditDialog.small(editDialog);
    }
    
    promise.then(function (ctrl) {
      var input = ctrl.getInput();
      
      input.$viewChangeListeners.push(function () {
        input.$setValidity('test', input.$modelValue !== 'test');
      });
    });
  };
  
  $scope.toggleLimitOptions = function () {
    $scope.limitOptions = $scope.limitOptions ? undefined : [5, 10, 15];
  };
  
  $scope.getTypes = function () {
    return ['Candy', 'Ice cream', 'Other', 'Pastry'];
  };
  
  $scope.loadStuff = function () {
    $scope.promise = $timeout(function () {
      // loading
    }, 2000);
  }
  
  $scope.logItem = function (item) {
    console.log(item.name, 'was selected');
  };
  
  $scope.logOrder = function (order) {
    console.log('order: ', order);
  };
  
  $scope.logPagination = function (page, limit) {
    console.log('page: ', page);
    console.log('limit: ', limit);
  }
}]);
```

```css
body,
md-content {
  background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
}

body > md-toolbar {
  z-index: 3;
}

md-toolbar.md-table-toolbar.alternate {
  color: #1e88e5;
  background-color: #e3f2fd;
}

md-toolbar.md-table-toolbar.alternate .md-toolbar-tools {
  font-size: 16px;
}

md-card:first-child {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 24px;
}

.checkboxes > md-checkbox {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 16px;
  min-width: 300px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.width-override{
  width:40px !important;
  padding:0px !important;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="demoApp">

  <head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Demo</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table/master/dist/md-data-table.css">
    
  </head>

  <body layout="column">
    
    <md-toolbar class="md-whiteframe-1dp">
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <div class="md-title">Material Design Data Table</div>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    
    <md-content laout="column" flex ng-controller="nutritionController">
      
      <md-card>
        <div layout="row" layout-wrap class="checkboxes">
          <md-checkbox ng-model="options.rowSelection">Row Selection</md-checkbox>
          <md-checkbox ng-model="options.multiSelect">Multiple Selection</md-checkbox>
          <md-checkbox ng-model="options.autoSelect">Auto Selection</md-checkbox>
          <md-checkbox ng-model="options.decapitate">Decapitate</md-checkbox>
          <md-checkbox ng-model="options.largeEditDialog">Lard Edit Dialogs</md-checkbox>
          <md-checkbox ng-model="options.boundaryLinks">Pagination Boundary Links</md-checkbox>
          <md-checkbox ng-model="options.limitSelect" ng-click="toggleLimitOptions()">Pagination Limit Select</md-checkbox>
          <md-checkbox ng-model="options.pageSelect">Pagination Page Select</md-checkbox>
        </div>
      </md-card>
      
      <md-card>
        
        <md-toolbar class="md-table-toolbar md-default" ng-hide="options.rowSelection && selected.length">
          <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <span>Nutrition</span>
            <div flex></div>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="loadStuff()">
              <md-icon>refresh</md-icon>
            </md-button>
          </div>
        </md-toolbar>
        
        <md-toolbar class="md-table-toolbar alternate" ng-show="options.rowSelection && selected.length">
          <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <span>{{selected.length}} {{selected.length > 1 ? 'items' : 'item'}} selected</span>
          </div>
        </md-toolbar>
        
        <md-table-container>
          <table md-table md-row-select="options.rowSelection" multiple="{{options.multiSelect}}" ng-model="selected" md-progress="promise">
            <thead ng-if="!options.decapitate" md-head md-order="query.order" md-on-reorder="logOrder">
              <tr md-row>
                <th md-column md-order-by="name"><span>Dessert (100g serving)</span></th>
                <th md-column md-order-by="type"><span>Type</span></th>
                <th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="calories.value" md-desc><span>Calories</span></th>
                <th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="fat.value" class="width-override"><span>Fat (g)</span></th>
                <th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="carbs.value"><span>Carbs (g)</span></th>
                <th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="protein.value"><span>Protein (g)</span></th>
                <th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="sodium.value" hide-gt-xs show-gt-md><span>Sodium (mg)</span></th>
                <th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="calcium.value" hide-gt-xs show-gt-lg><span>Calcium (%)</span></th>
                <th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="iron.value" hide-gt-xs show-gt-lg><span>Iron (%)</span></th>
                <th md-column md-order-by="comment">
                  <md-icon>comments</md-icon>
                  <span>Comments</span>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody md-body>
              <tr md-row md-select="dessert" md-on-select="logItem" md-auto-select="options.autoSelect" ng-disabled="dessert.calories.value > 400" ng-repeat="dessert in desserts.data | filter: filter.search | orderBy: query.order | limitTo: query.limit : (query.page -1) * query.limit">
                <td md-cell>{{dessert.name}}</td>
                <td md-cell>
                  <md-select ng-model="dessert.type" placeholder="Other">
                    <md-option ng-value="type" ng-repeat="type in getTypes()">{{type}}</md-option>
                  </md-select>
                </td>
                <td md-cell>{{dessert.calories.value}}</td>
                <td md-cell class="width-override">{{dessert.fat.value | number: 2}}</td>
                <td md-cell>{{dessert.carbs.value}}</td>
                <td md-cell>{{dessert.protein.value | number: 2}}</td>
                <td md-cell hide-gt-xs show-gt-md>{{dessert.sodium.value}}</td>
                <td md-cell hide-gt-xs show-gt-lg>{{dessert.calcium.value}}%</td>
                <td md-cell hide-gt-xs show-gt-lg>{{dessert.iron.value}}%</td>
                <td md-cell ng-click="editComment($event, dessert)" ng-class="{'md-placeholder': !dessert.comment}">
                  {{dessert.comment || 'Add a comment'}}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </md-table-container>

        <md-table-pagination md-limit="query.limit" md-limit-options="limitOptions" md-page="query.page" md-total="{{desserts.count}}" md-page-select="options.pageSelect" md-boundary-links="options.boundaryLinks" md-on-paginate="logPagination"></md-table-pagination>
      </md-card>
    </md-content>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table/master/dist/md-data-table.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```