# Re size angularjs material design data table column width

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I have used md-table with angularjs material, Here i tried to re size column with but always display like following in style property I need help to re size this property.

```
table.md-table:not(.md-row-select) th.md-column:nth-child(n+2):nth-last-child(n+2) {
    padding: 0 56px 0 0;
}
```

I also tried following way but not wroking "[adjusting angularjs material design data table column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738835/adjusting-angularjs-material-design-data-table-column-width)"

Answer (score 0):

```
I have fixed the following way. The class name "table-reszie-column" i used for table. Here 5 px is my requirement you can change as per your choose

.table-reszie-column:not(.md-row-select) td.md-cell:nth-child(n+2):nth-last-child(n+2),
.table-reszie-column:not(.md-row-select) th.md-column:nth-child(n+2):nth-last-child(n+2)
 {
    padding: 0 5px 0 0 !important;
}
```